# Can not change host-Only adapter settings in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I am using virtualbox 4.3.12 on Windows 7
I would change the host only adapter settings in file > Preferences > Network > Host-Only Network.
After I add the new ip address and click on save, the Virtualbox is switch it to 192.168.x.x

I tried with command line

```
VBoxManage.exe hostonlyif ipconfig "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" --ip 10.20.0.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I got the same result. The VBOX not want to change it for me.:-(

Comment: i am facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same Issue here. Cannot change subnet mask

Answer (score 2):

I found how to fix this issue.

Run Virtual Box as Administrator when you want to go and edit the settings.

I am using Virtual Box V3.3.30